# How to create a for loop to obtain correlations from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following data frame:

```
Gene <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6")
A1.1 <- c(1,1,2,4,3,5)
B1.1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
C1.1 <- c(2,2,3,5,5,5)
A1.2 <- c(1,2,3,5,5,5)
B1.2 <- c(3,2,5,6,6,6)
C1.2 <- c(1,1,2,2,4,6)
df <- data.frame(Gene, A1.1, B1.1, C1.1, A1.2, B1.2, C1.2)

   Gene A1.1 B1.1 C1.1 A1.2 B1.2 C1.2
1    1    1    1    2    1    3    1
2    2    1    2    2    2    2    1
3    3    2    3    3    3    5    2
4    4    4    4    5    5    6    2
5    5    3    5    5    5    6    4
6    6    5    6    5    5    6    6
```

So I need to obtain correlation values between columns of the same letter. So obtain the correlation values for A1.1 and A1.2, B1.1 and B1.2, and C1.1 and C1.2 for a total of 3 correlation values.

I can do this by using the `cor()` function for each (eg. `cor(df$A1.1, df$A1.2)`), but is there a for loop I could create that could obtain the correlations for all these at once?

Comment: Do you always have only 2 columns with the same starting letters? What is the expected output if there are more columns with the same letter?

Comment: There are other columns with the same letter but have a 2 instead (ie. A2.1, A2.2, B2.1, B2.2, C2.1 and C2.2),

Comment: And do you also want to obtain correlation values between column ```A1.1``` and column ```A2.1```?

Comment: No I would like to obtain correlation values between A1.1/A1.2 and then between A2.1/A2.2

Comment: Please edit your question then because it implies that you only care about the letter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `split.default`:

```
sapply(split.default(df[-1], sub('.\\d+$', '', names(df)[-1])), 
              function(x)cor(x[[1]], x[[2]]))

       A1        B1        C1 
0.9042908 0.8546548 0.7656415
```

If there are many columns with the same names:

```
 lapply(split.default(df[-1], sub('.\\d+$', '', names(df)[-1])), cor)
$A1
          A1.1      A1.2
A1.1 1.0000000 0.9042908
A1.2 0.9042908 1.0000000

$B1
          B1.1      B1.2
B1.1 1.0000000 0.8546548
B1.2 0.8546548 1.0000000

$C1
          C1.1      C1.2
C1.1 1.0000000 0.7656415
C1.2 0.7656415 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more columns with the same letter, correlation matrices might be more convenient to use, as you need to compare all columns with all the other columns

```
cor_list <- list()

col_names <- colnames(df[-1])
column_letters <- unique(substr(col_names, 1, 1))

for (let in column_letters){
  indices <- substr(colnames(df),1, 1) == let
  cor_list[[let]] <- cor(df[indices])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your columns are as nicely arranged as shown, you can correlate the pairs.

```
sapply(0:2, function(i) cor(df[, 2 + i], df[, 5 + i]))
# [1] 0.9042908 0.8546548 0.7656415
```